# ejs contentFor is not defined error when using renderFile

Tags: javascript, express, ejs

I needed to add html tags in then block of ejs therefore rendered ejs file using ejs.renderFile like this:

index.html

```
import APP from "./app.js"
import ejs from 'ejs'

APP.set('layout', 'layout')
APP.get('', async (req, res) => {
  const html = await ejs.renderFile('contents/ejs_pages/index.ejs', {async: true});
  res.send(html);
})
```

layout.ejs

```
<body>

<section>
<%- section %>
</section>

</body>
```

index.ejs

```
<%- contentFor('section') %>
<h1>This is section</h1>
```

Then below error that didn't occur when I was using res.render instead of ejs.renderFile occured.

```
Uncaught ReferenceError ReferenceError: contents/ejs_pages/index.ejs:1
...
contentFor is not defined
```

Can't I use contentFor in ejs when I'm using ejs.renderFile?
If so, is there any alternative?